# Application not utilizing GPU

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, gpu

I am using Topaz Gigapixel AI to enhance photos, and one of it's requirements is GPU. 
My problem is my notebook computer has two GPU one is embedded with GPU [Vega 8 GPU] and a separate one which is Radeon RX560X and that Gigapixel AI keeps on using the embedded GPU instead of the dedicated one.

Although I have set the GPU to use via Graphic Settings on Windows:

[As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BEbX.png)

Still looking at the Task Manager when processing a photo/image the application still utilized the embedded GPU what could I be missing?

Comment: Contact the developer. They need to implement a GPU selection setting in the software.